# Does the positivity/negativity of an ERP tell us anything at all?

Tags: neurolinguistics

In neurolinguistics, we come across event-related potentials such as N400 for semantic unexpectedness or P600 for error correction. Is there anything at all, linguistic or not, that we can infer from the positivity or negativity of such a signal? For example, spatial orientation of the source neurons, mechanism of creation, or anything else?

Comment: By _negativity,_ are you referring to negative EMF, negative affect, pain, or what? You surely can't be referring to [syntactic or semantic negativity](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf). I hope, anyway.

Comment: I refer to the negativity that the "N" in [N400](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N400_(neuroscience)) stands for, i.e. the electric potential of the brainwaves (= EMF; I wasn't aware of that abbreviation.)